# Compare values in dataframe column by fractions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

[image]

I need to compare index of the last month (within a group of id) with two previous months and check if it's the same.

I'm trying code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
               'month':[202001,202002,202003,202004,202001,202002,202003,202004,202001,202002,202003,202004,],
               'index':[3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  2,  3,  3,  3]})

df['check']=np.where(df.sort_values(['id', 'month'])
                             .groupby('id')['index']
                             .apply(lambda x: x.shift(3))
                             .transform('nunique')>1,1,0)
```

It returns error: ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results

Without "apply" the code works. What am I doing wrong?

The desired output is something like this:
[image]

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby.shift` and subtract from `index` then `clip` the upper limit to 1:

```
df['check'] = df['index'].sub(df.groupby("id")['index'].shift(2)).clip(upper=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

    id   month  index  check
0    1  202001      3    NaN
1    1  202002      3    NaN
2    1  202003      3    0.0
3    1  202004      3    0.0
4    2  202001      4    NaN
5    2  202002      4    NaN
6    2  202003      5    1.0
7    2  202004      5    1.0
8    3  202001      2    NaN
9    3  202002      3    NaN
10   3  202003      3    1.0
11   3  202004      3    0.0
```

Comment: Great @anky. This works! Thank you for the solution and the tip about "clip"

Answer (score 1):

You can just operate `shift` comparison with original in `transform`

```py
df['check'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'month']).groupby('id')['index'].transform(lambda group: group != group.shift(2)).astype(int)
```

```
print(df)
    id   month  index  check
0    1  202001      3      1
1    1  202002      3      1
2    1  202003      3      0
3    1  202004      3      0
4    2  202001      4      1
5    2  202002      4      1
6    2  202003      5      1
7    2  202004      5      1
8    3  202001      2      1
9    3  202002      3      1
10   3  202003      3      1
11   3  202004      3      0
```

Then change the first two rows in `check` column to `''`

```py
df['check'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'month']).groupby('id')['check'].transform(lambda group: ['', '']+list(group[2:]))
```

```
print(df)

    id   month  index check
0    1  202001      3      
1    1  202002      3      
2    1  202003      3     0
3    1  202004      3     0
4    2  202001      4      
5    2  202002      4      
6    2  202003      5     1
7    2  202004      5     1
8    3  202001      2      
9    3  202002      3      
10   3  202003      3     1
11   3  202004      3     0
```

Comment: Thank you @Ynjxsjmh. This is very clear solution. I've never tried transform group. This is much better for this case.